# How to create responsive navbar in angular like clickup.com

Tags: angular, menu, navbar, responsive, angular10

I'm new in web development I had a hard time to deal with angular 10 + responsiveness. I need to create a navbar like ClickUp without using any theme
please check here - https://clickup.com/

Comment: Hi Ayush, welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question really needs to be far more focused, showing the actual problem you're having, and you need to show that you have put some work into researching how to solve it. Responsiveness works the same in Angular as in the rest of web development.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**
Iv'e created small working demo of this concept [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-stwnzq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css), Enjoy!

My suggestion is to do it using angular material components, few basic things to start with:

1. [Toolbar](https://material.angular.io/components/toolbar/overview) - starts transparent after some scrolling become white with opacity animation.
2. [Sidebar](https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/overview) - open when 3 clicked, should be on top of content with `mode="over"`.
3. Menu button inside the Toolbar.